# findAllByBoolean running a query multiple times in JPA

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I have a user entity table in which there is a foreign key relation ship to another entity called user jobs. I have the following two queries in repository. While one of them is running very fast. the second query based on a boolean value is running the foreign key relation query multiple times than required.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User{
    @Id
    @NotNull
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private UUID id;

    private String title;

    private String companyId;//is the primary key of company table

    @Column(name = "is_active", columnDefinition = "BOOLEAN")
    private Boolean isActive;

    @OneToMany(
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true,
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER
    )
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SELECT)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Set<UserJobs> userJobs = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Here is my repository:

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, UUID> {

    Set<CompanyUser> getAllByCompanyId(String companyId);

    Set<CompanyUser> getAllByIsActive(Boolean isActive);

}
```

when I enabled, show sql query logs, I see that, for the `getAllByCompanyId` ,Hibernate run a query to user_jobs table for each user, it is still ok. But for the function `getAllByIsEnabled` it is running more than 3000 queries(users table has only 100 rows and jobs has only 2 rows) which doesnt seem right and something is messed up.

Can someone point out what could be the possible reason.

for reference I am using spring mvc with hibernate.

Comment: Did you get the response perfectly ? And are you returing your entity in response ?

Comment: yes. after quite siometime it returns the response.